# How to use the node.js module 'nodeunit' with coffeescript files

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, nodeunit

I'm trying to get the nodeunit module working within a coffeescript project but can't seem to get even a basic test to run.
  Here's my example Coffeescript
    require 'nodeunit'

```
test = true
test2 = false

exports.testSomething = (test) ->
  test.expect(1)
  test.ok(true, "this should pass")
  test.done()

exports.testSomethingElse = (test2) ->
  test2.expect(1)
  test2.ok(false, "this should fail")
  test2.done()
```

Unfortunately, when I run '$ nodeunit example.coffee' I get the error output:

> example.coffee:4 exports.testSomething = (test) ->
>                                   ^
>
> module.js:296
>       throw err;
>       ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
>       at Module._compile (module.js:397:25)
>       at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
>       at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
>       at require (module.js:346:19)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node/nodeunit/lib/nodeunit.js:75:37
>       at /usr/local/lib/node/nodeunit/deps/async.js:508:13
>       at /usr/local/lib/node/nodeunit/deps/async.js:118:13
>       at /usr/local/lib/node/nodeunit/deps/async.js:134:9
>       at /usr/local/lib/node/nodeunit/deps/async.js:507:9

Can anyone help me just get a simplified test up and running in Coffeescript using Node.js?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your example runs fine for me. It could be that you're using an old version of nodeunit, before it had CoffeeScript support; try

```
npm install -g nodeunit
```

to update to the latest version.

If that fails, then I suspect that it's a path issue, so that when nodeunit tries to do `require 'coffee-script'`, it fails.

First do

```
npm install -g coffee-script
```

and take note of the last line of the output, which should look something like

```
coffee-script@1.1.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
```

Now run

```
echo $NODE_PATH
```

which in my case is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. You need to set `NODE_PATH` to the parent directory of the `coffee-script` directory that npm created, by adding a line like

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

to `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or whatever else it is your shell runs when it starts, and restart your shell. Then whenever you do `require 'coffee-script'` from any Node app on your machine, it'll find the CoffeeScript library.

Comment: Phenomenal detective work.  My $NODE_PATH was empty, but none of my other modules cared.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1028416 You should mark his answer as correct, then.  While you are at it, consider giving the answer a +1. We work for cred on Stack Overflow.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If your coffee-script is version 1.7 or later, you may also be suffering from [bug #247](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/issues/247), for which I just submitted a [patch](https://github.com/hildjj/nodeunit/commit/60d1195c2a232a96544e3c93ece29b22f5429b32).